# How to make a nice fraction in subscript?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, fractions

I wrote

```
\begin{equation}
M_{\frac{1}{2}}= ...
\end{equation}
```

but it doesn't look very nice. fraction is too small and and "tight", and when I add `\dfrac` that is too big. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit, "subscript" seemed a more appropriate word than "index".

Comment: There is `\nicefrac` in the `units` package...

Comment: @marmot i tried that but then it looks like 1/2 and I don't want that

Comment: you haven't provided a full example so can not see what it looks like for you but if using the default fonts at the default size I would use `M_{\frac{1}{2}}` or (depending on the meaning)  `M_{0.5}`

Comment: I prefer $M_{1/2}$.

Comment: Out of interest which version out of the accepted answer did you choose? To me, of the ones shown  "Normal frac" looks by far the best with "Inline" being the only other possibility.  `tfrac` and `dfrac` are not really options for a subscript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't forget `nicefrac`.  And, as erik notes, `\sfrac` of the `xfrac` package.  Finally, I added a `\scriptscriptstyle\frac{}{}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac,xfrac}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M_{\nicefrac{1}{2}}&= \text{ nicefrac}\\
M_{\sfrac{1}{2}}&= \text{ sfrac}\\
M_{\scriptscriptstyle\frac{1}{2}}&= \text{ \texttt{scriptscriptstyle frac}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\sfrac{1}{2}` from the `xfrac` package.

Comment: The kerning looks off in the `sfrac` example. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 17):

You have several options:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
M_\text{\textonehalf}&= ... \text{ The smallest}\\
M_{\frac{1}{2}}&= ... \text{ Normal \texttt{frac}} \\
M_{\tfrac{1}{2}}&= ... \text{ In-between, \texttt{tfrac}}\\
M_{\dfrac{1}{2}}&= ... \text{ Displaystyle \texttt{dfrac}} \\
M_{1/2}&= ... \text{ Inline}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LY]